# Subscribe to sensor_msgs/PointCloud

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, subscribe, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i have a node that publishes sensor_msgs/PointCloud data and i want to subscribe to this.
My Subscriber looks like this:

```
distance_sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/distance_sensors", 1, &SafetyBelt::distanceCallback, this);
```

I included the point_cloud.h and the point_types.h headers. But i am not able to compile this Code and i have no idea what the error means:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/subscribe_options.h:111:54:   required from ‘void ros::SubscribeOptions::init(const string&, uint32_t, const boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&)>&, const boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<X>()>&) [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>; uint32_t = unsigned int]’
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:443:5:   required from ‘ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const M>&), T*, const ros::TransportHints&) [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>; T = SafetyBelt; std::string = std::basic_string<char>; uint32_t = unsigned int]’
  /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/src/SafetyBelt.cpp:16:121:   required from here
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:138:31: error: ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>’
       return M::__s_getDataType().c_str();
                                 ^
  In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:34:0,
                   from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                   from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                   from /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/include/SafetyBelt.h:1,
                   from /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/src/SafetyBelt.cpp:1:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h: In instantiation of ‘static void ros::serialization::Serializer<T>::read(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference) [with Stream = ros::serialization::IStream; T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>; typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&]’:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:163:32:   required from ‘void ros::serialization::deserialize(Stream&, T&) [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>; Stream = ros::serialization::IStream]’
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:136:34:   required from ‘ros::VoidConstPtr ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<P, Enabled>::deserialize(const ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams&) [with P = const boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >&; Enabled = void; ros::VoidConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const void>]’
  /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/src/SafetyBelt.cpp:81:1:   required from here
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:136:5: error: ‘class pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>’ has no member named ‘deserialize’
       t.deserialize(stream.getData());
       ^
  In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:37:0,
                   from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:34,
                   from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                   from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                   from /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/include/SafetyBelt.h:1,
                   from /home/daniel/Desktop/robotino/trunk2/trunk/robotino/robotino_teleop/src/SafetyBelt.cpp:1:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value() [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]’:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:122:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value() [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]’:
  /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:139:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
```

Can anyone tell me how to correctly subscribe to this topic?

Best regards
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192707/subscribe-to-sensor_msgs/pointcloud/) by [Missing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19975/missing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview, for a subscriber that receives pcl::PointCloud objects directly:

```
// Need to include the pcl ros utilities
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"

// callback signature, assuming your points are pcl::PointXYZRGB type:
void callback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr&);

// create a templated subscriber
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > (topic, queue_size, callback);
```

Are you sure you included `<pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>`, not just `<pcl/point_cloud.h>`?

If you can post a [gist](http://gist.github.com) of your full node, I can take a look.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Missing](https://answers.ros.org/users/19975/missing/) on 2014-09-16**:
Thank you very much paulbovbel, that solved my problem :)